# How to see through trees and foliage during battle?

Tags: warhammer-total-war

Is there a way to make trees and foliage more transparent when in Battle. At the moment when starting in any forested areas the foliage is really dense and impenetrable. I find it really hard to see what's happening and before I know it one of my flanks is routing. I've looked in graphics settings but not found anything specific.

Comment: Having never played this game specifically before, I can't vouch for the games intended functionalities. However, having played the original board game (yes; I'm old), line-of-sight is interrupted by thing such a foliage/trees etc, causing effects that would limit visibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you press and hold the space bar during Battle mode then an option menu pops up. This allows you to enable / disable various things, one of which is to 
'Hide foliage'. Once checked, during battle press and hold the space bar again to see your troops through trees or alternatively you can click the "lock" icon next to the 'Hide foliage' option so it will hide automatically.

Comment: could you explain a bit more?

Comment: @DMK Please don't use suggested edits just to add bold.  They don't help readability.  For more information, [read this meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11504/is-emboldening-questions-a-good-practice)

Comment: The main reason for that edit was to correct a spelling mistake 'I' to 'If' as it effected the readability of the answer. However one character changes are not allowed, hence the bold.

Comment: @DMK Don't add superflous edits just to get past the character limit.  If there's not enough wrong with it to actually hit the limit, then it doesn't need to happen.  Let someone with 2K do it.

Answer (score -1):

I solve my similar problem not by the game option but by the touchpad option.

Try if "maintain spacebar" lock your pointer also outside of the game. Yes? You have to solve this pad constructor issue first.

That will unlock your mouse in the  "maintain spacebar" tw wh battle interface, so the access to a left side option sub-menue, ntm tree visibility switch.

Comment: Welcome to the site! It is not clear what you are trying to say here, what do you mean by '"maintain spacebar" lock'? Are you reiterating the above answer?